# Allow element to appear over scrollbars

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover, scrollbars

I am trying to build a mouse-over-menu that appears when hovering over an element. This works great, however, for the bottom-rows the hover disappears in the scroll-bars.

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:1024px; height:50px; overflow:scroll; border: 1px solid red;">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <span style="margin-left:5px" class="checkboxlink ignore"></span>

            <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="checkboxlink todo"></span>Te doen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="checkboxlink done"></span>Behandeld</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="checkboxlink ignore"></span>Negeren</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="checkboxlink park"></span>Parkeren</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        .... more divs
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 0px solid white;
    vertical-align: top;

}

.dropdown:hover
{
border: 0px solid #ccc;

}

ul{
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.dropdown:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

See also here:

https://jsfiddle.net/w030L59t/

I tried positioning absolute, but the element still stays in the scrollable area.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to restructure the html code or do you need a solution for exact the same DOM structure?

Comment: First of all, in your inline code from the first div should be "height", and NOT "heigh". And second, why do you need the overflow and that fixed height? Can you give us an example of what it should look like?!

Comment: I need about this dom structure, as it is generated. Sorry about the `height` typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is any `position: relative` attribute for the dropdown parents. If you remove them, you can easily add `position: absolute` to your dropdown, to display it above the scrollable box:

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/w030L59t/1/)</kbd>

The problem removing `position: relative` is that the position of each dropdown is calculated once on page load. While the dropdowns work great without scrolling, you will notice in the demo, that each dropdown does not refresh its position.

---

This could be solved using a few lines of javascript, calculating the `.offset.top` of each parent after scrolling and updating the dropdowns position using `top: <offset.top of its parent>`. I have added the classes `.list_item` and `ul.dropdown_list`, although the ID `#wrapper`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // fire function everytime the wrapper is scrolled
    $('#wrapper').scroll(function(){

    // set element to relate to
    var list_items = $('div.list_item');

    // get each position
    list_items.each(function() {

      // store offset().top inside var
      var list_item_position = $(this).offset().top;

      // select previous dropdown_list item
      $(this).prev().find('ul.dropdown_list').css({

        // apply offset top
        top: list_item_position + "px"

      });
    });

    // write to console to track changes
    console.log('positions updated');

  }); // .scroll

}); // document.ready
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE DEMO WITH jQUERY**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/w030L59t/5/)</kbd>

Comment: How would I go about updating the 'top'?

Comment: @RobAu Hey, I have written a short script to demonstrate one possibility. Hope this helps. You can although achieve this without adding the classes if thats not possibly, did this for readability.